# Terminology confusion - basis of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a bit of a dumb question. I'm currently taking a linear algebra course. Right now we're working with operators and just finished up diagonizability. So I know this definition:

> An operator $T:V\to V$ is called diagonalizable if and only if there exists a basis $B$ of $T$ such that $B$ consists of eigenvectors.

I know that every operator has a matrix representation. But I don't quite understand what a "basis of $T$" would be. Do we mean a collection of vectors in $V$ such that the columns of $T$ will form a diagonal matrix? Or do we mean a basis for the domain or image of $T$? Or perhaps something entirely different?

Comment: It should be “a basis of $V$”.

Answer (score 0):

An operator $T:V→V$ is called diagonalizable if and only if there exists a basis B such that $[T]^B_B$ is a diagonal matrix (Hence the term diagonalizable). $[T]^B_B $ is a diagonal matrix if and only if $B$'s elements are eigenvectors.